# Pascal Arrays Can't figure out how to print info from arrays

Tags: arrays, pascal

I'm trying to write a program tracks the products made by 7 machines in a factory, which all make the same 10 kinds of products.

The program asks the user to enter the machine id (A, B, C...G)
Then the product id (0, 1, 2...9)
and finally the program asks for a 0 or 1 to mark the product as either good quality or bad quality.

I put all of that information into three arrays. What I have to do next is the part I'm stuck with. I have to create two tables from all that information.

The first table is a table of good quality products. It has to be a two dimensional table with the MachineIDs running along the top and the ProductIDs running down the side.

There needs to be a running total for every single machine and every single product. So, in the cell [A0] needs to be a total of how many times machineA has made product0 and it was marked as GOOD. Then [A1] and so on all the way to [G9]

The second table is exactly the same only this time only the bad products are counted.

At the bottom there needs to be a total of ALL products made by each machine. Down the right hand side there has to be a total of ALL the individual products made be all machines.

Here's my code so far.

```
program Production;

var machine: array of char;
  var product: array of integer;
  var quality: array of integer;
  var min, number, extra: integer;
  var machineID: array[1..7] of char;
  var productID: array[1..10] of char;
  var x, y, count: integer;

begin

  x:= 0;
  y:= 0;
  number := 0;
  min := 5;
  extra := 5;
  SETLENGTH( machine, min );
  SETLENGTH( product, min );
  SETLENGTH( quality, min );
  writeln('Input Machine ID ( A, B, C, D, E, F or G ) ');
  readln(machine[number] );
  while (machine[number] <> '*') do
  begin
    while ( ORD( machine[number] ) < 65 ) or ( ORD( machine[number] ) > 71 ) do
    begin
      writeln('Input Invalid. Please try again.');
      readln(machine[number] );
    end;
    writeln('Input Product Number ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9 ) ');
    readln(product[number] );
    while ( product[number] < 0 ) or ( product[number] > 9 ) do
    begin
      writeln('Input Invalid. Please try again.');
      readln(product[number] );
    end;
    writeln('Quality Control Check. Input 0 for GOOD or 1 for BAD.');
    readln(quality[number] );
    while ( quality[number] <> 0 ) and ( quality[number] <> 1 ) do
    begin
      writeln('Input Invalid. Please try again.');
      readln(quality[number] );
    end;
    number := number + 1;
    writeln('Input Machine ID ( A, B, C, D, E, F or G ) ');
    readln(machine[number] );
  end;
  for count := 0 to number - 1 do
      begin
        writeln('Machine ID = ',machine[count] );
        writeln('Product ID = ',product[count] );
        writeln('Quality = ',quality[count] );
      end;
  writeln('');
  writeln('');
  writeln('EXIT');
  readln;
end.
```

Could anyone tell me even how I would go about it? I'm completely at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem a bit differently. After I've recorded all the input from the user for one piece of data (machine, product and quality), I'd store it in a table - or in this case in a three-dimensional array. If I recall correctly, you can create such thing as follows:

```
var myTable: array[1..7, 1..10, 1..2] of integer;
```

The dimensions of the table would come as follows:

- 1..7 would be the machine Ids
- 1..10 would be the product Ids
- 1..2 would be the good/bad.

Once I got all the input from the user, I would simply increment the appropriate field in the table. E.g. assume the user inputs are: { machine B, product 2, Good } then we would

```
myTable[1, 2, 0] := myTable[1, 2, 0] + 1;
```

Therefore when we would want to print out our table we could just:

```
for i := 0 to 7 do
    begin
    for j := 0 to 10 do
        begin
            write(myTable[i,j,0] + ' ');  { i,j,0 for the good; i,j,1 for the bad values }
        end;
    writeln('');
    end;
```

Comment: This is a good way of doing it. However I have to use letters for the Machine IDs. It's part of the assignment. Is there a way that I can work around that and use a version of the code you've written? It's so much simpler than anything I've been trying :D

Comment: `ORD( machine[number] ) - 65` would turn A, B, C ... into 0, 1, 2, ..., wouldn't it? :)

Comment: Haha I guess it would. 

Thank you for helping me. I'm really new at this and I'm trying to take it all in but it's all so complex (to me anyway). 

How should I implement the

       myTable[1,2,0] := myTable[1,2,0] + 1
piece of the code?

Comment: I've written this line of code after the quality number is input:

    `myTable[number] := myTable[(ORD(machine[number])-65),(product[number]), (quality[number])];`    

I keep getting errors saying :    


Production2.pas(44,31) Error: Incompatible types: got "LongInt" expected "Array[1..10] Of Array[1..2] Of LongInt"

Comment: You create an integer variable, say `machineIndex`. `machineIndex` is going to be `ORD(machine[number]) - 65`. Then after you asked for everything from the user you could pretty much do a `myTable[machineIndex, product[number], quality[number]] := myTable[machineIndex, product[number], quality[number]] + 1;`

Comment: After I get all input for one piece of data I have this code:    `myTable[machineindex,(product[number]),(quality[number])] :=
    myTable[machineindex,(product[number]),(quality[number])] + 1;`   Then for the tables I have this:    `for i := 0 to 7 do
    begin
    for j := 0 to 10 do
        begin
            write(myTable[i,j,0], ' ');
        end;
    writeln('');
    end;`   with 0 replaced by 1 for the second table. There are two tables but say I input A, 0, 1. Then the second table has the numbers 1 5 0 1 0 0 0 7 0 5 on the top row(A) instead of 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.

Comment: Do you have any idea where all those extra numbers are coming from?

EDIT: I've tried it again but this time put in B,1,0. This time the first table is perfect. But the second table reads 0 5 0 1 0 0 0 7 0 5 along the top row. The same as before except without the 1 that I input last time.

Comment: Hmm... maybe write a loop at the very start to reset everything to 0. I have no other clue ...